# Break Quarter into Months in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to break the quarters into months. In source I have `2019Q1` but I need to break the one record into 3 records

```
empid Quarter earnings
-----------------------
 123    2019Q1  4000
 456    2019Q2  6000
```

Desired result:

```
mpid  Month        earnings
---------------------------
 123  January 2019   4000
 123  February 2019  4000
 123  March 2019     4000
 456  April 2019     6000
 456  May 2019       6000
 456  June 2019      6000
```

Comment: So what's stopping you here? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Do you have a calendar table? If not, I suggest investing in one.

Comment: Please read [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This reminds me of those crime drama television shows where they have a photograph captured by a camera at the crime scene that's a little blurry.  All they have to do is say "enhance" and they get a better resolution.  It's easy to roll up monthly data into quarterly data, but you can't just say "enhance" and change quarterly data into monthly data.

Comment: But if you do this and sum up the months, now suddenly your Q1 of 2019 has earnings of **12'000** - not 4'000 ... magically multiplying your earnings here .....

Comment: @marc_s - but what if it *did*? It's a great business plan if you can do it!☺

Comment: Well I dint posted what I tried but here what I'm getting with the query I wrote want to break my source column into mothyear
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dateadd(Month,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),'2019-01-01')) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(dateadd(Month,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),'2019-01-01')) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month YYYY]

Its not like I dint tried but forgot to post my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Larnu suggested, a Calendar Table is well worth the effort.  That said, here is an option that performs a 1-to-many join to an ad-hoc table

**Example**

```
Select empid
      ,MonthYear = datename(month,datefromparts(left(Quarter,4),MM,1))+' '+left(Quarter,4)
      ,Earnings
 From YourTable A
 Join (
        Select *
         From  ( values (1,1) 
                       ,(1,2) 
                       ,(1,3) 
                       ,(2,4) 
                       ,(2,5) 
                       ,(2,6) 
                       ,(3,7) 
                       ,(3,8) 
                       ,(3,9) 
                       ,(4,10) 
                       ,(4,11) 
                       ,(4,12) 
               )B1(QQ,MM)
      ) B on right(Quarter,1)=QQ
```

**Results**

```
empid   MonthYear       Earnings
123     January 2019    4000
123     February 2019   4000
123     March 2019      4000
456     April 2019      6000
456     May 2019        6000
456     June 2019       6000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the "earnings" value by month, then you just need to setup a CTE to match the Q# with the corresponding months and add that to your query.